# What is the syntax for starting a sqoop2 job?

Tags: cloudera, sqoop2

i've set up a sqoop2 job, and i'm trying to start it like so:

```
~]$ sqoop2
Sqoop home directory: /usr/lib/sqoop2
Sqoop Shell: Type 'help' or '\h' for help.

sqoop:000> submission start
Exception has occurred during processing command 
Unknown command: No such property: start for class: groovysh_evaluate
```

which seems to be incorrect. help lists start as a command, so i tried this:

```
sqoop:000> start 2
The specified function "2" is not recognized.
```

also seems incorrect.

what is the correct syntax here?

---

PS:

```
sqoop:000> show version
client version:
  Sqoop 1.99.2-cdh4.5.0 revision  
  Compiled by jenkins on Wed Nov 20 15:52:52 PST 2013
```

Comment: I got same issue too.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [documentation](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/sqoop2-1.99.2-cdh4.5.0/CommandLineClient.html#start-command), you should use following command:

```
start job --jid 1
```

Comment: the documentation is out of sync - i don't remember what happened when i tried that, but i'll check and update with the effects

Comment: The documentation seems to be accurate - you just need to use the proper one for your exact CDH version.

Answer (score 0):

In sqoop2 command for jobs:

**show job commands:** it will help you to watch list of all created jobs.

```
show job
```

if you wanna to watch individual job configuration then try

```
show job -jid 1    # here 1 is < job id number >
```

**Start Job Commands:** once you created job you can start job created job id number.

```
start job -jid 1   # here 1 is < job id number >
```

**Show Submission jobs:** Once you started jobs you can watch all jobs submission status. it will also show you previously ran job submission status.

```
show submission
```

**check individual job status:** you can also check current job or previously ran job status by this command.

```
status job -jid 1    # here 1 is < job id number >
```